# Given a String how to convert it to an Array: Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

so I'm pretty new at Java and StackOverflow (That's what they all say) and I am stuck at the given problem:

My method is given a String e.g.: `"[ 25 , 25 , 125 , 125]"`. Now the method should return an Array of integers representation of the String provided, that is: it should return 
`[25,25,125,125]`.

Here is a segment of my method. Note: input is the String provided

```
if(input.charAt(index) == '['){
    index++;
    int start = index;

    while(index <= input.length() && input.charAt(index) != ']'){
        index++;
    }

    String[] arrayStr = input.substring(start, index).split(",");
    int[] arrayInt = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++){
        arrayInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i]);
    }
    return arrayInt;
```

My code works if input is: `"[25,25,125,125]"` (If there are no spaces between the numbers).
However if there are spaces between the numbers then my code doesn't work and I understand why, but I am struggling to find a way to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the javadoc of String. It has methods like trim(), indexOf() and lastIndexOf() that you should use. And don't assume your array has 4 elements. Use `arrayStr.length`.

Comment: Can your string contain only `[numbers]` or can it also be in form `some words [numbers, xxx] other words`?

Comment: Why not simply remove all spaces, before processing? `String s = input.replaceAll("\\s", "");`

Comment: @Pshemo Yes the string can only be `[numbers]`, if there are any words within the square brackets I'll have to return an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces will fail with `Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i])` (e.g. the string "25 " is not a valid number as it contains a space. (`parseInt` will throw an exception in such cases.)

However you can solve it quickly by trimming your array elements:

```
Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i].trim())
```

`trim()` returns a copy of the string without leading/trailing white space

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the space with empty in the string

```
input=input.replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. remove `[` and `]` and all spaces
2. split on `,` to get all tokens
3. iterate over all tokens

   - parse string number to int
   - add parsed int to result array

So your code can look like

```
String data = "[ 25 , 25 , 125 , 125]";
String[] tokens = data.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s", "").split(",");
int[] array = new int[tokens.length];
for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
    array[i]=Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```

Or if you have Java 8 you can use streams like

```
int[] array = Stream.of(data.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s", "").split(","))
        .mapToInt(number -> Integer.parseInt(number))
        .toArray();
```